# How to get Maxima to collapse expressions with i^2

Tags: complex-numbers, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

Example from attempting to reproduce https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Example:

I've got Maxima to generate:

```
1/abs(%i*omega^3+2*omega^2-2*%i*omega-1)^2
```

$$\frac{1}{{{\left| i {{\omega}^{3}}+2 {{\omega}^{2}}-2 i \omega-1\right| }^{2}}}$$

which is equivalent to

$$1 \over ω^6 + 1$$

if ω is positive, but how do I get Maxima to do this simplification?

I've tried `declare(omega, real)`, `assume(omega>0)`, `ratsimp`, `trigsimp` `gfactor` etc. etc. but nothing works.

[Wolfram Alpha has no problem simplifying it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fabs(i*%CF%89%5E3%2B2*%CF%89%5E2-2*i*%CF%89-1)%5E2&t=ietb01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cabs` and `expand` the result.

[Explanation](http://maxima-discuss.narkive.com/MrVlQMze/abs-cabs) (contributed by @endolith):

> `abs` is a simplifying function
>
> `cabs` is a routine.
>
> The distinction is that `abs` is for when you want to *express* the concept of absolute value; `cabs` is for when you want to *change the form* of the
> expression to make it more explicit.

Comment: Also you can use `(subst(abs=cabs, %o1), ev(%%));` to process `abs` as if it were `cabs` in an existing expression. [ref](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/maxima-discuss/thread/slrnpfn96a.539.robert.dodier%40freekbox.fglan/#msg36318550)